# Applying a command-line flag to Chrome at auto-launch

Tags: windows, command-line, google-chrome

*(Windows 8.1)*

Chrome auto-launches for me when I log in, and I like that. The problem is that the Disable New Avatar Menu flag [recently stopped having any effect](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513899), so the only way to actually disable it is to pass the `--disable-new-avatar-menu` flag on Windows. I've got it set up in all of my shortcuts, but Chrome's auto-launch registry key is at `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`, and the key is `GoogleChromeAutoLaunch_<string of alphanumerics>`. The key's value has the path to Chrome, as expected, with the flag `--no-startup-window`. I've tried adding additional flags to that key but they're removed when I log in again.

How can I permanently attach command-line flags to Chrome when it auto-launches at login?