# How to launch Edge browser with command line flags?

Tags: command-line, browser, windows-registry, windows-11, microsoft-edge

My question is similar to this:

[Applying a command-line flag to Chrome at auto-launch](https://superuser.com/questions/946867/applying-a-command-line-flag-to-chrome-at-auto-launch)

But 7 years later, on Edge browser, on Windows 11.

I knew a way that'd make it possible to add flags to Edge browser when launched by clicking on a link in an app, but I forgot it. if I remember correctly, it was done using registry.

So I already add a command line flag to Edge shortcut's target on desktop and taskbar, like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --enable-features=Feature1
```

that's the target of the Edge shortcut on desktop. the feature I enable like that only takes effect when I launch Edge from the shortcut.

but I want that feature to be always enabled, even when I don't use the shortcut on desktop and instead launch Edge by clicking on a link in the mail app or some other app.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the method I had used in my OneNote notes.

so, Edge browser, assuming you are using the stable channel which is preinstalled, we have to navigate to this registry folder:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\open\command
```

then modify the value of the Default key, from:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --single-argument %1
```

to:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --enable-features=Feature1 --single-argument %1
```

it is important to add `--enable-features=Feature1` before `--single-argument %1`, otherwise it won't work.

`--single-argument %1` is necessary to be there, otherwise after clicking on a link in Mail app or OneNote app, Edge browser opens with new tab page instead of opening the link you clicked on.

If using other channels of Edge such as Dev, then the Default key's value should be pointing to the correct executable, like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\msedge.exe" --enable-features=Feature1 --single-argument %1
```

Same can be done for Beta and Canary channels.

finally, you can use this built in page to check which feature flags are enabled:

```
edge://version/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Jameschad - Why are you replying to a comment generated by a user selecting the option in a review queue? Nobody get's notified if you ping that particular user.  You should still take the feedback into consideration.